# const and non-const parameter function overloads with a single definition

Tags: c++, function, overloading

I have the following 2 function overloads:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
void func(F f, std::vector<T>& v) { ... }

template<typename F, typename T>
void func(F f, const std::vector<T>& v) { ... }
```

The body of both of them is the same.
Is there an easy way to define them both with a single definition to avoid code duplication using C++17 or earlier standard?

Just to clarify, I want the functions to be constrained based on the `std::vector` part but I want to allow const and non-const references to be passed.
The reason I need both overloads is that the `F` function object will be applied to the vector and sometimes `F` will modify the vector and sometimes it will only observe the vector (and I want to allow the vector to be declared `const` in the second case).

I guess I can use C++20 concepts to constrain the function template parameter but I was wondering if there's an easy way to achieve the same thing using C++17 or earlier version of the standard.

Comment: Perfect forwarding may be an alternative, if you ignore the possibility of rvalues being passed to the function which would result in `v` being non-const instead of `const`...

Comment: If two functions do two different things they are two different functions. So I would start by giving func two different names. And inject different `f`'s into them as well. (Don't do code reuse for the sake of code reuse, keep your concepts and intentions visible)

Comment: @fabian I was thinking about perfect forwarding but how can I keep the `std::vector` constraint? I think that perfect forwarding can only accept unconstrained types.

Comment: `template<typename F, typename T> void func(F f, T& t)`. That's all. There is no need to mention `vector`. If you really need it, add a `static_assert` in the body to prevent calling with non-vector types, but it doesn't really provide any benefit. Tomorrow or in three years you will want to call `func` with things other than `std::vector`. (Ask me how I know. Yes, been there, done that.)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I already have 2 functions overloads for when F returns void and when it doesn't (`func_void` and `func_nonvoid`) and now if I need to add 2 more overloads based on the constness of the second parameter I will have 4 overloads (`func_void_constarg`, `func_void_nonconstarg`, `func_nonvoid_constarg` and `fun_nonvoid_nonconstarg`) and it seems like an overkill especially since the const and non-const versions can have the same body.

Comment: @PepijnKramer what if `func` is really `std::for_each` in disguise? Does your reasoning apply to `std::for_each` too? Do we need two (or ten or 10000000) different `std::for_each`?

Comment: You don't need `func_void` and `func_nonvoid` either. Use `auto func(whatever)` (one overload).

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough, good counter example :)

Comment: @n.m. The functions participate in a function overload along with other versions for `std::list`, `std::string`, `std::optional`, etc. I *really* need to make sure the right overload is chosen. That's why I need the `std::vector` constraint.

Comment: Your `func` looks like [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) where `d_first == first1`.

Comment: Does your `std::list` overload do something different from `std::vector` overload? If som you are on a dangerous path.

Comment: @n.m. `std::list` does the same thing but `std::optional` doesn't :)

Comment: Why would you overload a function on both container types and `std::optional`?

Comment: OK, let me clarify what I'm trying to achieve from a more general point of view.
I want to achieve a similar design to the stream operators. They can accept any type given that you provide a function overload for it. The difference is that output stream operator needs only const arguments, so you don't have to define 2 overloads but in my case I should be able to accept both const and non-const arguments.

Comment: @Nelfeal I want to create an overload set which can be extended by future types as well. The function in question is called by a library I'm writing and that's why I need to provide a way for the user to define a specific handling for their own types. This is where the function I'm talking about comes into play.

Comment: If the `std::list` overload does the same thing as the `std::vector` overload, they should be the same function. If the `std::optional` overload does something different from the `std::vector` overload, they should have different names.

Comment: you can always do sfinae in earlier version.

Comment: @appleapple I was afraid that this is the only viable option prior to concepts.

Comment: @ЗамфирЙончев no, SFINAE can (at least almost) always achieve same thing as `require` clause. just more complicated (and not much in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution but it still adds a little bit of overhead:

```
template<typename F, typename VecT>
auto func_vec(F f, VecT& vec)
{
  //actual code
}

template<typename F, typename T>
auto func(F f, std::vector<T>& vec) { return func_vec(f, vec); }

template<typename F, typename T>
auto func(F f, const std::vector<T>& vec) { return func_vec(f, vec); }
```

A third function is defined (`func_vec`) which holds the actual implementation of `func`.

Note that `typename VecT` can accept both `const` and non-`const` arguments.

`func` overloads are just used to constrain the argument to be of type `std::vector<T>&` with or without a `const` qualifier.

The good thing about this solution is that it doesn't use SFINAE and is fairly easy to read.
The bad thing is that you have to introduce another function template for the actual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `require` clause to do sfinae,

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_vector : std::false_type{};
template<typename ...Args>
struct is_vector<std::vector<Args...>> : std::true_type{};

template<
    typename F,
    typename C,
    std::enable_if_t<is_vector<std::remove_cvref_t<C>>::value,std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
>
void func(F f, C&& v) {
   // ...
}
```

<sup>* `std::remove_cvref_t` is still c++20, you need to use `std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>` in earlier standard</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that there's no easier way to tell the overload system that you want both const and non-const arguments of a specific type.
That is until C++20 where you can define a concept for this purpose very easily.

Comment: @ЗамфирЙончев yes concept make it a little shorter to *use* (but you can just put same trait inside `enable_if`). *define* the trait doesn't seems to change much though.